# Adding to/editing the URL bar of a webpage without deleting what's already there.

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

I need to add some text to a URL bar without deleting what's already there(as I've mentioned in the title). Basically, I have eight or so hashes(/one/, /two/, /three/, etc).

I have to add these to the URL bar without deleting the previous hashes that are already in there. For example, I could have a button that adds "/two/" to the URL, but what if "/one/" is already there? I need it to make it so that it just adds the new hash after the one one, like this - "/one/two/three/".

I've tried using

`<a href="/one/">Hide "one"</a><br/>`

and

`<a href="/two/">Hide "two"</a><br/>`,

but unfortunately when I use the second one after the first, it just replaces "/one/" with "/two/".

Any suggestions would be great. Let me know if I need to provide some more context, I'm not quite sure what's relevant to this question in my code.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen, especially when you're using a "local absolute" path (`/....`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a function

```
<a onclick="addHash('/one/');">One</a>
<a onclick="addHash('/two/');">Two</a>

function addHash( hash ) {
    window.location.hash = window.location.hash + hash;
}
```

You will probably need to do some checking in the addHash function to see if it exists already, but thats a good place to start.

Comment: Great answer, just what I was looking for. Thanks for the straight forward solution!

Comment: You need to either remove the trailing or leading slash. Otherwise it will result in #/one//one//one//one//one/

Comment: Yeah, I had to learn that the hard way(wasn't that hard, haha).

@Samosa I have a question though. To work, the URL has to have "#hash" at the end, right? But they might not hit the button for "one" first, so I can't just make it so that when they click a button it adds "#hash" to the URL. Is there a way in JavaScript to check for "#hash" in the URL, and if it's not there, add it? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "To work, the URL has to have "#hash" at the end". When you set the hash via window.location.hash it will check if the hash exists if it doesn't it will add and then add the hash parts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little more description on what you are trying to achieve here?
Are you just trying appearance of the URL, or are you trying to navigate to pages with these arguments?

I'm sure PHP would solve this with the following but I'm not sure why you would use it.

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>/one">One</a>
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>/two">Two</a>
```

If you're using jQuery you could do:

```
<a href="/one" class="addToUrl">One</a>
<a href="/two" class="addToUrl">Two</a>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.addToUrl').click(function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname + href;
        });
    });
</script>
```